# Azure Migrate doesnt dectect data disk on VMWare Ubuntu Guest VM

Tags: azure, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to migrate an Ubuntu VM to Azure using Azure Migrate. I have already downloaded and install the AzureMigrate Appliance and connected to my VMware Vcenter and all the VM's have been detected and reported to the Azure Portal.

My problem is that the Ubuntu VM (Ubuntu server 18.04) that I want to migrate has 2 disks, the OS disk with 80GB and the data disk with 6TB. Bouth disks are connected to the VM the same way (via VMWare), but the data disk (on /dev/sdb1) is not detected by Azure Migrate. Also, both disks are EXT4.

Is there any requirement on the disk in Linux/Ubuntu that Azure migrate need to properly detect the disk?

Regads,
Amedina

Comment: As mentioned, contact support, they might help. 
Alternatively, you can try using free alternatives to migrate VM to cloud. I've done the migration using StarWind V2V. https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/ConvertingtoMicrosoftAzure.html

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to disk [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-azure-enable-replication#resolve-common-issues).

**Resolve common issues**

- Each disk should be smaller than 4 TB.
- The operating system disk should be a basic disk, not a dynamic disk.
- For generation 2 UEFI-enabled virtual machines, the operating system
  family should be Windows, and the boot disk should be smaller than
  300 GB.

Comment: Hi, and thank you very much for you reply, but I the documentation for Azure Migrate says the limit is 8TB --> http://aka.ms/dependencyagentwindows , maybe the 4TB limit is for other tool/service?

Comment: You are welcome :) I saw this doc too, but the doc I sent described replication for Vmware VM. It is not the same information, in this case, I believe that you should raise a ticket to Microsoft in order to confirm which one contains the right information.